# How can I calculate the sum for rolling a pair of dice

Tags: probability

[image]

I’ve been looking at this question and I’m pretty confused. I thought it meant that the tally was the amount of ways you can receive the sum. For example, to get a sum of 2, you can only get a (1,1) so that’s only one way. But I don’t know what the difference between that and “number of times” is. Am I missing something important?

Comment: A tally means he *did* this.  He sat down, rolled the dice.  Got a result and he made a check mark to keep track of his result.  Then he rolled the dice again.  He did this  14 times.  And he got a 2 once, he didn't ever roll a 3, he rolled a 4 two times, and so on.  Now if you sat down and rolled a dice 14 times you'll probably get different results because you are not John and you are doing this at a different time.

Comment: The question is simpler and more practical than you think.  In this particular experiment a sum of $2$ happened one time, a sum of $3$ zero times, a sum of $4$ two times, and so on

Comment: Yea, this is just how many times John got those sums. You just have to write the equivalent number in the second column, i.e., 1, 0, 2, 1...

Comment: The difference between "tally" and "number of times" is that the "tally" is what you write down *while* you are doing the experiment and the "number of times" is what you write down as a final result after the experiment is done.  It doesn't make sense to write down "1" the first time he gets a $4$ and then two cross it out and right down "2" the second time.  So this is the sheet while he is in the middle of an experiment.

Comment: So the exercise is telling you to write down: $1,0,2,1,2,4,2,1,0,1,0$ the the last column.